# Wordpress Site only showing main page under Xampp

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, xampp

Sorry for the same problem again, but I have tried various solutions provided by other people and still cannot solve this problem.

I have twice pulled a live website (which works fine) down to run locally under XAMPP Version 5.6.31. The first time I did everything manually, but could not solve this problem. I deleted that installation and tried again using the Duplicator plugin, but ended up with the same problem.

The website main page has a menu on it which takes the user to different pages (not posts) on the website. Each page is based on an individual template which loads the page. Examples of the standard codes used to move from one page to another are:

```
1. <a href="/index.php/user-login/">user Login</a>
2. echo "<script type='text/javascript'> document.location = '/index.php/user-login/'; </script>";
```

The localhost website files are in c:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite. I can login to Wordpress and edit the website pages, view the plugins etc.

I have set the wp-config.php to the correct database-name/root/no-password settings, tried saving the permalinks (pressing SAVE twice), tried changing the permalinks, checked the .htaccess file, corrected the Xampp config settings of "AllowOverride" and "mod_rewrite", checked I can access the database using Xampp MySQL, checked the database permissions and tried different settings in "c:\xampp\htdocs\index.php".

If I type "http://localhost/mywebsite/index.php/user-login" into the browser, the correct login page is displayed. If I hover over the menu option on the main page of mywebsite, "localhost/index.php/user-login" shows in the bottom left corner of Firefox. Pressing that just refreshes the main page - it does not take me to the login-page.

c:\xampp\htdocs\index.php includes the lines:

```
$uri .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
header('Location: '.$uri.'/mywebsite/index.php');
```

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated - thanks.

Comment: Check your developer tools in your browser - does it really just refresh the home page, or is there a (quick, barely noticeable) redirect happening?
Is the behavior identical with and without a trailing slash on the login URL?

Comment: @janh2 - The presence or not of the trailing slash do not make any difference. I cannot see any sign of a redirect happening. Thank you for your ideas.

Comment: This may not be the greatest idea, but it worked in the end. I created a variable $_SESSION["folder"], which I set to "" on the live system and "my-extra-directory" in the Xampp system. Now the code is: `echo "<script type='text/javascript'> document.location = '{$_SESSION["folder"]}/index.php/user-login/'; </script>";` instead of `echo "<script type='text/javascript'> document.location = '/index.php/user-login/'; </script>";`